# Simple tensors in the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and assume, if necessary, that $X^*, Y^*$ have the [approximation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) (but not necessarily the [Radon–Nikodym property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_property#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property)). Consider the injective tensor product $X\otimes_\varepsilon Y$. For all $f\in X^*$, $g\in Y^*$ one can form a functional $f\otimes g$ by

$$(f\otimes g)(x\otimes y)= \langle f,x \rangle \cdot \langle g, y \rangle.$$

Is the subspace $\mbox{span}\{f\otimes g\colon f\in X^*, g\in Y^*\}$ weak* dense in $(X\otimes_\varepsilon Y)^*$?